# Could not find Qt Designer in PyQt 5.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I am new to Python, so I tried to experiment with tkinter for a while, but then I decided to skip to PyQt5. I installed it through "pip install pyqt5", but I cannot find Qt designer. I found out it was included into .exe bundles, but they are not provided anymore on the official website. Should I install the whole Qt bundle?

Comment: The pip install will effectively only give you a runtime for PyQt5 aplications. If you're on Windows, there's currently no separate installer for the dev-tools. Someone has started an unofficial [pyqt5-tools wheel](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-August/037852.html) for this, but it still appears to be in its infancy, so I cannot vouch for it in any way.